# PDO return last ID in a class

Tags: php, class, object, pdo

I am a bit stuck on how to use return last ID using PDO. All the tutorials/answers I have found are based on it not being in a class so struggling to find an answer.

The code I've got is below. It all works apart from returning the last id. When returned true it inserts in database and redirects to another page. Am I using return ID correctly? And if so, how do I echo the ID on the page that the user is redirected to?

EDIT: thanks for the answers - I have updated the code to replace 'true' with return last id part. However, I am still struggling to return the ID, have added the new code below. The database insertion is working correctly, I am just struggling to output what is returned.

Thanks,

The database query:

```
public function insertNewCustomer($data){
    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO Customers (First_Name, Surname, Email) VALUES (:firstname, :surname, :email)");
    //Bind Data
    $this->db->bind(':firstname', $data['firstname']);
    $this->db->bind(':surname', $data['surname']);
    $this->db->bind(':email', $data['email']);


    //Execute
    if($this->db->execute()){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

    //Get ID of new customer
    $lastID = $this->db->lastInsertId();



}
```

How I am trying to echo out the ID:

```
$itinerary = new Itinerary;

$template->ID = $itinerary->insertNewCustomer();

echo $ID->lastID;
```

New code to try and echo out ID:

```
if(isset($_GET['firstname'])){

$data = array();
$data['firstname'] = $_GET['firstname']; 
$data['surname'] = $_GET['surname']; 
$data['email'] = $_GET['email']; 

if($itinerary->insertNewCustomer($data)){

echo $itinerary->insertNewCustomer();


} else { echo 'did not work';}
```

Comment: `$lastID = $this->db->lastInsertId();` is correct but your code never reaches it because you are returning after `$this->db->execute()`

Comment: this `echo $ID->lastID` does not make any sense

Comment: everything write after a return isn't executed so your code never pass to $lastID = $this->db->lastInsertId();

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because you are returning before running `db->lastInsertId();`

Change this:

```
//Execute
if($this->db->execute()){
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}   

//Get ID of new customer
$lastID = $this->db->lastInsertId();
```

To:

```
//Execute
if($this->db->execute()){
    return $this->db->lastInsertId();
} else {
    return false;
}
```

`$itinerary->insertNewCustomer();` will now return false on failed execute or the insert id.

Comment: @4each What on earth are you trying to achieve with these edits? The last edit you suggested added only a whitespace character. Please stop before I ask for a mod to step in.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// Use this function

    public function insertNewCustomer($data){
        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO Customers (First_Name, Surname, Email) VALUES (:firstname, :surname, :email)");
        //Bind Data
        $this->db->bind(':firstname', $data['firstname']);
        $this->db->bind(':surname', $data['surname']);
        $this->db->bind(':email', $data['email']);


        //Execute
        if($this->db->execute()){
        //Get ID of new customer
            return $this->db->lastInsertId();
        } 
        return false;
    }
```

// Out of function scope
    $itinerary = new Itinerary;

```
$template->ID = $itinerary->insertNewCustomer(); // Call to function

if($template->ID!==false){echo "Customer ID". $template->ID;}
else{
echo "Customer insertion failed";
}
```

Comment: `$ID->lastID` makes no sense to me.

Comment: @DanielO. Fixed. Thanks

Comment: This solution adds nothing that I didn't add. `is_numeric` isn't even required because `$itinerary->insertNewCustomer();` will only ever produce `false` or an integer.

Comment: It would be better to enable the PDO Exceptions via the PDO constructor options to handle database related errors.

Comment: @DanielO.I agree that you can handle PDO exception internally in the insertion function.